# C++ Overloading the plus operator to add an element to an object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Constructor for object

```
Set<T>::Set() {
    buckets = new forward_list<T>[9];
    numBuck = 9;
    numElem = 0;
    maxLoad = 9;
}
```

Overloading of plus operator

```
Set<T>::operator+(T elem){
    Set<T> res;
    return res;
}
```

I don't quite know where to begin with this. This overloaded operator add its parameter `elem` to a copy of *this and return the result.
ex:

```
Set<char>setA;
Set<char>setB;

setA.Add('a')
setA.Add('b')
setA.Add('c')
// setA contains {'a','b','c'}
setB = setA + 'd'
// setB should now contain {'a','b','c','d'}
```

Any guidance?

edit: Clarified operator overload functionality

Comment: Your operator needs a return type.  Your set needs a copy constructor.  Your implementation needs to copy the set and call `Add`.  Right now it's returning an empty set.  Read more about [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Comment: Your `void Add(x)` function modifies set, while your `operator+` returns a copy of original set with new element. possible implementation is `Set CopySetAndAdd(x) { 
auto copy = CopySet(); copy.Add(x); return copy; }`. If you don't have `Set CopySet()` operation yet, you need to implement it. Simplest (and safest, if you dont understand this datastructure implementation yet) implementation may just copy all elements to new set like `{ Set copy; for (...) { copy.Add(x); } return copy; }`

Comment: Is your question about  how to overload the `+` operator syntactically, or are you asking for help writing the body of the method?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I'm confused on how to begin the body of the method. I have overloaded the = operator to allow me to make a deep copy of &const otherSet parameter so I can do something like ``` setB = setA``` where setB will contain all the contents of setA

Comment: @Zayum: so your question is about how to implement a hash map?

Comment: *"This overloaded operator should allow me to do something like this."* -- this is a poor way to write functional specs for your operator. Example code is subject to interpretation, which leads to confusion, and confusion in design leads to crashes. You should write out what this operator is to do. For example, your spec might be: *This operator should add its parameter `elem` to a copy of `*this` and return the result.* One benefit of writing out clear specs is that they often tell you exactly what code to write.

Comment: I think my question is more how to syntactically access a copy of the first set without a parameter for it in the overloaded + method. How do I write "make a copy of setA and add the element to it" in "setA = setB + 'e'. ie using the overload + operator as another way of adding an element to the object (set in this case) @DanielMcLaury

Comment: I don't think you should use operator overloading for this (unless it's an assignment). Arithmetic operators are associated with calculations, and you shouldn't confuse users with other meanings. I know long time ago people chose the implement string concatenation with +. But the modern concensus is that was not a good decision. You should instead name the function something like 'add' or 'append'

Comment: @Zayum: When you write something like `SetA = SetB + 'e'` there are two separate things happening. First, you're calling the `+` operator, which creates and returns a new set.  Second, you call the `=` operator, which assigns this set to `SetA`.  These are not part of the same operation.

Comment: As of now I can get SetA = SetB to define SetA as a copy of SetB, but when I do SetA = SetB + 'c', the contents of SetB are not being copied over into SetA, but 'c' is added to SetA. I'm struggling to articulate my issue. @DanielMcLaury

Comment: @Zayum *"I think my question is more how to syntactically access a copy of the first set without a parameter for it"* -- this still covers two issues: **1)** accessing the first set and **2)** making a copy. The syntax for the former (`*this`) is in the question, so you are saying that the question is how to invoke the copy constructor (either `Set<T> res = *this;` or `Set<T> res{*this};`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a copy function in the set, and use the `Add` function inside the overload. Demo code:

```cpp
Set<T>::operator+(T elem)
{
    Set<T> result;
    result.Copy(*this);
    result.Add(elem);
    return result;
}
```

NOTE: Or you can follow @jxh's answer and use the default copy constructor. I would make a `Copy` function just to be explicit. :)

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

For the copy of `*this`, you can modify the definition of `res` to use the copy constructor.

```
Set<T> res(*this);
```

Adding the `elem` argument uses the same method you used for adding elements to `setA`.

```
res.Add(elem);
```

---

Since it looks like your code is managing a pointer, you will need to define your own destructor, to release the allocated memory.

```
Set<T>::~Set() {
    delete[] buckets;
}
```

You are also obligated to implement your own copy constructor and assignment operator, due to the Rule of Three. Your copy constructor would need to performs its own allocation, and the elements from the other `Set` need to be copied over.

```
Set<T>::Set(const Set<T> &other) {
    numBuck = other.numBuck;
    numElem = other.numElem;
    maxLoad = other.maxLoad;
    buckets = new forwardList<T>[numBuck];
    // ... add code to copy elements from other.buckets
}
```

The assignment operator can be implemented using the copy-swap idiom.

```
Set<T> & Set<T>::operator = (Set<T> other) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

---

To avoid needing to implement your own destructor / copy constructor / assignment operator methods, you can opt to represent your `buckets` with a `vector` rather than managing your own pointer.

```
    std::vector<forward_list<T>> buckets;
```